# Multiple similar panels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

In my app I'll have several JPanels (10 or more) with slight modifications each (additional buttons, labels etc).

So my idea was to create Panel class, with common elements ( 3 buttons, 3 labels and 3 textfields - they will be on every panel on the same location, of course with different data) - in my example below only 1 button, 1 label and 1 textfield.

And in my main class I'd like to change names of labels, set value in textfields, like in this panel which was created manually by me:

```
 p1.btn1.setText("TEST");
```

I hope you'll understand my explanations.. thanks.

What's the best method to do this correctly?

[image]

What I've done so far:

```
public class Main {

JFrame f;

Panel1 p1;
Panel2 p2;
Panel3 p3;

JButton btn2, btn3;
JPanel panel2, panel3;
JLabel lblSpeed2, lblSpeed3;
JTextField txtSpeed2, txtSpeed3;

public Main() {

    f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);

    p1 = new Panel1();
    p2 = new Panel2(btn2, panel2, lblSpeed2, txtSpeed2, "Panel no. 2");
    p3 = new Panel3(btn3, panel3, lblSpeed3, txtSpeed3, "Panel no. 3");

    f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.weighty = 0.0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    f.add(p1, c);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    f.add(p2, c);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    f.add(p3, c);

    p1.btn1.setText("TEST");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Main m = new Main();

}
  }
```

My manually created Panel:

```
public class Panel1 extends JPanel {

JButton btn1;
JPanel panel1;
JLabel lblSpeed1;
JTextField txtSpeed1;
Border blackline;

public Panel1() {

    super();

    blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray);

    panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    panel1.setBorder(blackline);
    panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory
            .createTitledBorder("Manually created Panel"));

    btn1 = new JButton("Btn 1");
    lblSpeed1 = new JLabel("Speed");
    txtSpeed1 = new JTextField(5);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.weighty = 0.0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 4;
    panel1.add(btn1, c);

    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panel1.add(lblSpeed1, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panel1.add(txtSpeed1, c);

    add(panel1);

}
```

}

Template for another panels:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {

Border blackline;

public Panel(JButton btnSend, JPanel MPanel, JLabel lblSpeed,
        JTextField txtSpeed, String Name) {

    super();

    blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray);

    MPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    MPanel.setBorder(blackline);
    MPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(Name));

    btnSend = new JButton("Btn 1");
    lblSpeed = new JLabel("Speed");
    txtSpeed = new JTextField(5);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.weighty = 0.0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 4;
    MPanel.add(btnSend, c);

    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    MPanel.add(lblSpeed, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    MPanel.add(txtSpeed, c);

    add(MPanel);

}
}
```

and finally my panel classes:

```
public class Panel2 extends Panel {

public Panel2(JButton btnSend, JPanel MPanel, JLabel lblSpeed,
        JTextField txtSpeed, String Name) {
    super(btnSend, MPanel, lblSpeed, txtSpeed, Name);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

and

```
public class Panel3 extends Panel {

public Panel3(JButton btnSend, JPanel MPanel, JLabel lblSpeed,
        JTextField txtSpeed, String Name) {
    super(btnSend, MPanel, lblSpeed, txtSpeed, Name);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).   2) `public class Panel extends JPanel {` a) Don't extend components unless changing them otherwise simply keep an instance. b) Don't call an extended Swing class the same name as an AWT class.  That is a recipe for confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kinda vague, it will come down to how you want to interact with the components on the container.

You could use a abstract class to represent the base concept of the class and implement each individual case

You could construct a model that describes each component and allow the component to construct the UI based on the requirements from the model.

The important thing to try achieve here is to maintain appropriate separation of responsibility

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is something not too good. You have a powerful and strong language that handles object, let's try to focus on how to work with them.

You simply wrote 3 "different" class with the SAME constructor and SAME structure.

WHY?

You can work with 3 different panel just creating 3 different instances: for example I change this code of you:

```
p2 = new Panel2(btn2, panel2, lblSpeed2, txtSpeed2, "Panel no. 2");
p3 = new Panel2(btn3, panel3, lblSpeed3, txtSpeed3, "Panel no. 3");
```

The result is the same, but you have just only one class

I'm going to lunch, then I explain to you better. hang on